# Calcular e imprimir promedio de calificaciones en materias asociadas a alumnos. (Impresión de boletas por alumno en lote)

Tags: php, mysqli

En este código de FPDF imprimo valores de **n** materias con calificaciones de alumnos de **x** grupo consultado con la sentencia SQL.

Lo que hace es imprimir una boleta con calificaciones y materias por alumno en páginas diferente.
Por ejemplo si el grupo 100 tiene 23 alumnos con 11 materias cursando,  se imprime en PDF en un solo archivo las 23 boletas de ese grupo, las materias y calificaciones de cada alumno se reflejan bien en la boleta, pero ahora buscaba calcular el promedio de cada una de ellas dentro de un bucle while.

En el `if` que esta dentro del `while`, compara el valor de una variable inicializada con el primer `idAlumno` recuperado de la tabla, si coinciden imprime las calificaciones del primer `idAlumno`, de no coincidir imprime la de los demás alumnos. Pero así como lo tengo sólo imprime el promedio calculado correctamente de la primera boleta, pero del segundo en adelante imprime otros promedios, creo que esta tomando valores salteados, tal vez esta mal el lugar donde estoy colocando las impresiones o el calculo.

El bucle while engloba las impresiones de los datos en celdas, dentro de while esta el if y el promedio lo puse dentro del else.
 Intentaba que el divisor ("contador") para calcular el promedio (sobre el número de materias) sea variante, ya que el número de materias varía.

¿Algún error que puedan ver u otra forma de implementarlo?

Este es el código (***lean los comentarios en las partes relevantes***):

```php
<?php

require('conexion.php');
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF 
{
    function AcceptPageBreak()
    {
        $this->Addpage();

        //$this->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
        $this->Ln();
    }

        function Header()
    {
        //logo
        $this->Image('logo2.png',10,8,33);
        //fuente
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
        //movernos a la derecha como sangria
        $this->Cell(65);
        //movernos a la derecha como sangria
        $this->Cell(70,10,'CEB: Listado Grupo',1,0,'C');//tamaños,texto,contorno 1, salto de linea despues de la selda, alineacion
        //salto de linea
        $this->Ln(20);
    }

    function Footer()
    {   //desde hacia arriba 15 puntos, coordenadas, a 1.5 cm del final
        $this->SetY(-15);
        //arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        //num de pagina
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');

    }   
}

if( isset($_GET['periodo']) && isset($_GET['semestre']) && isset($_GET['grupo']) )  {

    $periodo = $_GET['periodo'];  //RECIBIMOS EL PARAMETRO POR URL : EL ID DE LA TABLA ALUMNO_GRUPO
    $semestre = $_GET['semestre'];
    $grupo = $_GET['grupo'];
}
//CONSULTA TRAE TODAS LAS CALIFICACIONES DE TODOS LOS ALUMNOS PERYECIENTES A CIERTO GRUPO,
$consulta = "SELECT A.idAlumno, A.matricula, A.nombre, A.grupo, P.periodo, AG.parcial1 as p1mat, AG.inasisP1 as ina1mat, M.materia, M.idMateria, G.idGrupo, P.descripcion, A.semestre, G.capacitacion FROM alumno A, alumno_grupo AG, grupos G, materias M, periodos P WHERE A.idAlumno = AG.idAlumno and G.idGrupo = AG.idGrupo and M.idMateria = G.materia and P.idPeriodo = G.periodo and P.periodo = $periodo and A.semestre = $semestre and A.grupo = $grupo ORDER BY A.nombre";
/////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////
$res=$mysqli->query($consulta);

$pdf = new PDF();

$pdf->Addpage();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// DATOS DEL ALUMNO  AL PRINCIO DE CADA HOJA
if ( $fila2 = $res->fetch_assoc() )   {

$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);

 //MATRICULA
 $pdf->SetX(19);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(25,5,$fila2['matricula'],1,0,'C',1);

 //NOMBRE ALUMNO COLPLETO
 $pdf->SetX(47);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(100,5,$fila2['nombre'],1,0,'C',1);//colocando ancho de celda

 //SEMESTRE
 $pdf->SetX(150);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(9,5,$fila2['semestre'],1,0,'C',1);

//PERIODO
 $pdf->SetX(161);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(24,5,$fila2['descripcion'],1,0,'C',1);

//CAPACITACION DONDE ESTA INSCRITO
 $pdf->Ln();
 $pdf->Ln();
 $pdf->SetX(78);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(40,5,$fila2['capacitacion'],1,0,'C',1);

//NUMERO DE GRUPO
 $pdf->SetX(120);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(8,5,$fila2['grupo'],1,0,'C',1);

 $pdf->Ln(); 
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 $pdf->Ln();
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 $pdf->SetX(22);//posisionamos en 10 de x  DATOS DE LA PRIMERA HOJA RECUPERADA CON LAS  CALIFS DE UN ALUMNO
 $pdf->Cell(109,6,'UNIDAD ACADEMICA CURRICULAR',1,0,'C',1);//colocando ancho de celda

 $pdf->SetX(132);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(25,6,'INASISTENCIAS',1,0,'C',1);//

 $pdf->SetX(158);
 $pdf->Cell(24,6,'CALIFICACION',1,0,'C',1);

 $pdf->Ln();
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $res2=$mysqli->query($consulta);

 //////////////////////////////////////////////// IMPRIMIENDO LOS VALORES DE LA TABLA //////////////////////////////
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
     $bandera = $row['idAlumno'] ;  //asignamos a bandera el valor del idAlumno recuperado del los registros

     //VARIABLES PARA EL CALCULO DEL PROMEDIO
     $suma = 0;
     $promedio = 0;

//WHILE
while ($fila = $res2->fetch_assoc())  //recuperando con array asociativo los califs de la tabla
{   
    //IMPRIMIENDO LAS CALIFICACIONES DEL PRIMER ALUMNO ENCONTRADO
    if ( $bandera ==  $fila['idAlumno'] ) { //si en los registros recuperados, cada idAlumno es igual a baendera
                                            //imprimir los califs que correcponden a ese alumno
    $pdf->SetX(22);
    $pdf->Cell(109,6, $fila['materia'],1,0,'C');

    $pdf->SetX(132);//nombre alumno
    $pdf->Cell(25,6, $fila['ina1mat'],1,0,'C',0);

    $pdf->SetX(158);
    $pdf->Cell(24,6, $fila['p1mat'],1,1,'C',0); 

    //ejemplo: valores obtenidos en la primera boleta (primer alumno)
    //ejemplo: calificaciones impresas = 8.7, 6.3, 6.7, 10, 8, 8.2, 5, 9.7, 8.2, 9.5, 8.4

    //suma = 88.7
   //promedio = 88.7/11 = 8.06 "CORRECTO"


    $valorFila = $fila['p1mat']; //variable toma el valor de la calificacion o nota de la metria
    $suma = $suma + $valorFila;  // variable que va acumulando cada valor
     //¿que funcion ocupar para que el divisor sea variable dependiendo el numero de filas encontradas;?
  } 
        //ELSE  :::  IMPRIMIENDO LAS CALIFICACIONES DEL SEGUNDO ALUMNO Y LOS DEMAS

  else { //si no corresponden imprime el resto de calificaciones recuperadas en hojas separadas

//CALCULO DEL PROMEDIO,////////////////////////////////////////////////
  $contador =11 ;  //n es el número de materias por las que hay que dividir la suma, buscaba que este valor fuera dinamico, de acuerdo al numero de materias encontradas,

  //CALCULO DEL PROMEDIO
  $promedio = $suma/$contador; //operaciomn
  $suma = 0;  //inicializando suma
    $pdf->Ln(3);
    $pdf->SetX(132);
    $pdf->Cell(25,6,'PROMEDIO:',1,0,'C',1); 

    $pdf->SetX(158);
    $pdf->Cell(24,6, round($promedio,2),1,0,'C',1);  //imprime promedio

    //ejemplo: valores obtenidos en la segunda boleta (segundo alumno)
    //ejemplo: calificaciones impresas = 8.2, 9.4, 7.7, 9.5, 8, 9.3, 9, 8.5, 10, 7.5, 10
    //suma = 88.8
   //promedio = 88.8/11 = 7.19 "INCORRECTO"

     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
    $pdf->Addpage();  //AGREGANDO PAGINA SIGUIENTE EN CASO QUE EL IDALUMNO NO SEA EL MISMO
    $bandera = $fila['idAlumno'];

    //MATRICULA
    $pdf->SetX(19);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(25,5,$fila['matricula'],1,0,'C',1);

     //NOMBRE ALUMNO COLPLETO
    $pdf->SetX(47);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(100,5,$fila['nombre'],1,0,'C',1);//colocando ancho de celda

    //SEMESTRE
    $pdf->SetX(150);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(9,5,$fila['semestre'],1,0,'C',1);

    //PERIODO
    $pdf->SetX(161);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(24,5,$fila['descripcion'],1,0,'C',1);

    //CAPACITACION DONDE ESTA INSCRITO
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->SetX(78);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(40,5,$fila['capacitacion'],1,0,'C',1);

    //NUMERO DE GRUPO
    $pdf->SetX(120);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(8,5,$fila['grupo'],1,0,'C',1);

    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Ln();

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $pdf->SetX(22);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(109,6,'UNIDAD ACADEMICA CURRICULAR',1,0,'C',1);//colocando ancho de celda

    $pdf->SetX(132);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(25,6,'INASISTENCIAS',1,0,'C',1);//

    $pdf->SetX(158);
    $pdf->Cell(24,6,'CALIFICACION',1,0,'C',1);
    $pdf->Ln();

        $pdf->SetX(22);
        $pdf->Cell(109,6, $fila['materia'],1,0,'C');

        $pdf->SetX(132);//nombre alumno
        $pdf->Cell(25,6, $fila['ina1mat'],1,0,'C',0);

        $pdf->SetX(158);
        $pdf->Cell(24,6, $fila['p1mat'],1,1,'C',0);     
        //por aqui buscaba imprimir el promedio de las calificaciones
  } //fin else
} //fin while (fila = res)

$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Comment: de acuerdo gracias saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues se me ocurren dos opciones.

Una es modificar tu query para que delegues a SQL la obtención del promedio y sólo te encargues de imprimirlo como un campo más.

La otra es que modifiques un poco tu código para que en la última iteración del while del alumno en cuestión, calcule el promedio.

Para la primera opción debe ser algo como:

```
$consulta = "
SELECT
  A.idAlumno, A.matricula, A.nombre, A.grupo, P.periodo, AG.parcial1 as p1mat, AG.inasisP1 as ina1mat, M.materia, M.idMateria, G.idGrupo, P.descripcion, A.semestre, G.capacitacion,
(SELECT AVG(calificacion1, calificacionN FROM tabla_con_calificaciones WHERE idAlumno = $idAlumno)) AS promedio
FROM
  alumno A, alumno_grupo AG, grupos G, materias M, periodos P
WHERE
  A.idAlumno = AG.idAlumno and G.idGrupo = AG.idGrupo and M.idMateria = G.materia and P.idPeriodo = G.periodo and P.periodo = $periodo and A.semestre = $semestre and A.grupo = $grupo ORDER BY A.nombre";
```

Es muy grande la query, aquí te pongo lo que podrías agregar:

```
(SELECT AVG(calificacion1, calificacionN FROM tabla_con_calificaciones WHERE idAlumno = $idAlumno)) AS promedio
```

Es una subconsulta dentro de tu consulta principal donde se obtiene el promedio de las calificaciones del alumno con id = $idAlumno, para esto se usa la función AVG de sql. Sólo tienes que colocar los parámetros correctos pues desconozco en qué tabla están esos datos y cómo se llaman.

La segunda opción si no quieres modificar tu query:

Primero creas un contador para el while:
Y crear el contador :

```
$i = 0;
while ($fila = $res2->fetch_assoc())  //recuperando con array asociativo los califs de la tabla
```

Luego colocar esto donde pusiste tu comentario:

```
  //¿que funcion ocupar para que el divisor sea variable dependiendo el numero de filas encontradas;?



 if ( $i === count($datos_array->fetch_assoc()) )
    {
       $promedio = $suma/count($datos_array->fetch_assoc();    
    }
$i++;
```

La lógica es:

> Voy a obtener el total de elementos del array que esté iterando.
>   Tendré un contador que vaya registrando las iteraciones. Cuando el
>   contador sea igual a la cantidad de elementos del array, es el último
>   ciclo; entonces calculo promedio y hago lo que quiera con él.

Y recuerda inicializar el contador a 0 de nuevo, podría ser en dentro del if.

Comment: si es cierto algo asi deberia ser, muchas gracias, saludos

Comment: @ArmandoArellano de nada, saludos :)